# how to post a binary file to server using dart http?

Tags: http, flutter, dart

There is a RESTfulAPI

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-LC-Id: Oi3HLMFEU2vgdMh4MI0MN9Np-gzGzoHsz" \
  -H "X-LC-Key: LW48oVxDd4yG5mteLCwqkGe0" \
  -H "Content-Type: image/png" \
  --data-binary '@test.png'  \
  https://$LC_API_HOST/1.1/files/test.png
```

I want post an image to this API :

```
File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
```

how to post it? every I post it, server can't receive the file.
please help me, thank you!

Comment: yes, it's free version, in order to the answer person convenient test. @bereal

Comment: Did you check [`http::post`](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/post.html)? It supports `List<int>` as a raw data body.

Comment: yes, I found if I set body as List<int>, Leancloud can't receive this data. I also run a expressjs server, it can't receive List<int> as well.

Comment: define: `"i cant receive"` - data is not sent or what?

Comment: @pskink Hi, thank you for help, in server perspective data is null.

Comment: If you are using curl command as a guide you can check out  https://pub.dev/packages/curl . It generates curl command from http client.

Comment: @GürkanSevinc haha amazing, that is good tool! thank you !

Comment: Dankee :) @WangJi